# Spring MVC how to create controller without return (String) view?

Tags: spring, controller

The below is my sample controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validatePage1 (@ModelAttribute("page1")
                        Page1 pg1, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("Value1:" + pg1.getVal1() + 
                "Value2:" + pg1.getVal2());

    return "page2"; // I don't want to take any action (page navigation) here
}

@RequestMapping("/page1")
public ModelAndView pageShow() {

    return new ModelAndView("page1", "command", new Page1());
}
```

Now the question is, I don't want to take any action in the client side when the method (validatePage1) is called by Spring framework, how to do?

Actually I have loaded all required pages in my client side at loading time (to avoid repeated page load), so I dont want to take any page navigation action in the client side, I just want to do the 'data binding' to complete my business logic in server side.

When I return "" empty string in "validatePage1()", Spring framework throws exception " Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException:" since I am using tiles, I have to remove tiles configuration later since I am loading all files at first loading itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-return-types):

> Supported method return types
>
> The following are the supported return types:
>
> [...]
>
> void if the method handles the response itself (by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse for that purpose) or if the view name is supposed to be implicitly determined through a RequestToViewNameTranslator (not declaring a response argument in the handler method signature).

Comment: Yes, I have tried with 'void' but I am getting exception as below:

Comment: message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: validate

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: validate
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:625)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: Don't try random things. READ the 4 lines of documentation in my answer. Especially the part that says "by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse for that purpose".

Answer (score 6):

You can set the method to return `void` and annotate it with `@ResponseBody`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371565/spring-mvc-request-with-no-view-rendered). No need to deal with `HttpServletResponse` etc.