# Spring controller should not do anything (void, response body)

Tags: spring, methods, controller, thymeleaf, void

I have an issue similar to this one, the solution does not work as I wished however:

[Spring MVC how to create controller without return (String) view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781046/spring-mvc-how-to-create-controller-without-return-string-view/20973865)

I have a form which should pass the file:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQQL0.png)

And the controller for it:

```
    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public @ResponseBody void uploadFile(Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws InterruptedException {
        //, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws InterruptedException {
Reservation reservation=new Reservation(  );
    fileService.uploadFile( multipartFile );
    File file = new File("\\car-rental\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\attachments", multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
log.info( "name and path " + file.getName() + file.getPath() );

Picname picname=new Picname();
            picname.setPicnameAsString(file.getName() );

log.info( "picname file " + picname.getPicnameAsString() );
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);



        }
}
```

I want the controller ONLY to perform the logic without returning anything: it returns however an empty page:

[empty page returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzgNS.png)

How can I make it not returning anything, just staying on the site with the form? The only idea was to set an delay with the .sleep(), but it would be a workaround and I would like to solve it with a cleaner solution

Comment: You always have a response, such is the nature of http (request and response). You at least need to send a status code. If you are using this in a MVC application, it will indeed return an empty view (as there is nothing to render).

Comment: Is there any workaround for it? do you have any idea how to do it? return a duplicated view?

Answer (score 0):

It is the nature of controllers to return a response since you are developing an MVC application which will receive POST requests to the endpoint you specified.

What you can do is declare the controller to be a @RestController which returns a ResponseEntity indicating that everything went OK or any other appropriate response in case some failure happens.

```
@RestController
public class ControllerClassName{
    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws InterruptedException {
        try{
            // logic
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }catch(Exception e){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To address your issue you may need to change the return type of your function.
Using a ResponseEntity return type may be more appropriate than using a ResponseBody return type.